# Implementing an interface from another project, which in turn references a 3rd party dll, and using types from that dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, reference

Hope my title wasn't too confusing ..

I have several projects in my solution, one of which contains only interfaces `MyProgram.Contract`. My plugins need to implement these interfaces.

In `MyProgram.Contract` I reference a 3rd party DLL for some types defined in it, such as one called `DataValue`.

in `MyProgram.MyPlugin` I reference `MyProgram.Contract` and implement the interface, and there is no problem with having a property `DataValue Value { get; set; }`, as defined in the interface. It compiles, and I can set the value of the `Value`-property from my main application and display it in my databound view in the plugin.

However, if I try to use `DataValue` in code in my plugin, I get the error "The type aThirdPartyLib.DataValue is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly aThirdPartyLib .."

This is what I was wanting to avoid. My wish is that the plugins need no other reference than to `MyProgram.Contract`. Is there a way to achieve this, or do I need to add all the same references in the plugin-projects as in the plugin contract project?

Answer (score 0):

If you use types from that DLL in your Interface definitions, then implementors of those interfaces will also need a reference to that DLL. No way around that, really.